# No route to host when deploying apache2 config to httpd service?

Tags: apache-httpd, docker

I have a strange issue: so far I was using `apache2` as proxy server (as docker container), 80 and 443 works without problems.

Now I'm trying to migrate to httpd container (v.2.4.54). But as soon as I start the httpd (same config as in apache2), I cannot reach my machine under its dns name anymore, nor can I ping it anymore on its public IP address.

BUT: I can reach it by internal hostname and internal IP without problems. So I assume the httpd server in correct in general, as all of my apps are reachable from internal.

But external is broken with `no route to host` error. I cannot `ping` or `telnet` anymore on the public ip or dns name.

What could be the problem here? How could a proxy server have an impact on the public ip/dns **at all**?

Comment: When you say, "I start the httpd", you mean start the *container*? Would that have an IP address and might that address conflict with the external address -- and win?

Comment: That phrasing is seen a lot when DNS is the source of the issue. Have you tried doing a DNS lookup on your domain name to see if things are ok in DNS land? Something like this: `dig hostname.domain.com @1.1.1.1`  or whatever DNS resolver you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LSerni indeed it turned out to be a loadbalancer / master-slave issue. The mechanism still watched for running apache2, this going into fail state when httpd was started.